# how to read more than 8192 byte with QTcpSocket?

Tags: c++, qt, qtcpsocket

i send a request to server and get a response my code is like this:

```cpp
QString mywindow::SocketCommunication(QString JsonRequest)
{
    QTcpSocket *socket = new QTcpSocket(this);
    QString result;
    socket->connectToHost(SOCKET_IP, SOCKET_PORT);//SOCKET_IP and SOCKET_PORT are defined constants and are correct

    if (socket->waitForConnected(-1) && socket->state() == QAbstractSocket::ConnectedState)
    {

        if (socket->write(JsonRequest.toLatin1()) == -1)
        {

            socket->disconnectFromHost();
            result = "Could not send message";
        }
        else
        {
            socket->flush();


            if (!socket->waitForReadyRead(90000))
            {
                socket->disconnectFromHost();
                result = "tcp con timeout for reading";
            }
            else
            {
                QByteArray JsonResponse = socket->readAll();// the problem is here

                socket->close();

                JsonResponse = JsonResponse.trimmed();
                QString jsonResp = QString::fromStdString(JsonResponse.toStdString());

                result = ParseResponse(jsonResp) // here i parse the response. it works fine and is not important in this question.
            }
        }
    }

    else
    {
        qDebug() << "cannot connect";
        socket->disconnectFromHost();
        result = "Could not Connect to Server";
    }
    return result;
}
```

now this works fine when ever the response coming from server is less than 8192 bytes. otherwise this only reads the first 8192 bytes. when i put `socket->error()` after read all i get -1 which is QAbstractSocket::UnknownSocketError. do you have any idea why this happens and how should i remedy it?

**ps**: i dont think the problem is the QAbstractSocket::DatagramTooLargeError which is

> The datagram was larger than the operating system's limit (which can be as low as **8192** bytes).

because i can send more than 8192 and other programs can communicate with larger messages all right.

Comment: Multiple calls to read? You must do that anyway with TCP, because since it's a streaming protocol there's no packages or beginnings or ends. A single receive can give you less than one message, a full message, or more than a single message.

Comment: do you mean like `socket->read(4096)` in a while? then what should be the condition in that while?

Comment: Multiple calls to read ***and*** write. The shown code appears to not fully check the return value of `write()` and, as such, may not actually write everything, depending on how Qt's wrapper for bezerkeley sockets works. The reason "other programs" can send and receive more stuff is because they actually understand how reading and writing from sockets works, and may not read or write everything, so they're specifically coded to have logic that tries agan, until everything is fully read and written.

Comment: You need to come up with a protocol on top of TCP, some way to tell you how much you need to receive. That can be done by using a fixed-sized message header containing the data length to receive, or by having a specific message or "package" separator that you check for. Or, like old HTTP, read until the connection is closed by the other end.

Comment: DataGrams are UDP concept, not TCP. You need to understand that TCP doesn’t work in packets. It’s a streaming protocol: You get one or more chunks of data, in spurts. You have no control on the size of the chunks; each might different; you are responsible for assembling those chunks yourself (they are correctly sorted). You also need to know when the data is done by means outside of TCP (i.e. knowing how many bytes in advance, or delimiters).

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that the `socket->write()` is a relatively low-level operation, which is part of the `QIODevice` API. It **will not** split your whole data into smaller chunks of <8192 bytes to comply to the TCP protocol requirements.

Hopefully, you can leverage `QDataStream` to send/receive data painlessly, without thinking of protocol implementations :

```
//send data
QDataStream sender(socket);
QByteArray dataWhichMightBeBiggerThan8192Bytes = jsonRequest.toLatin1();
sender << dataWhichMightBeBiggerThan8192Bytes;
```

To receive data :

```
//connect your socket
QObject::connect(
    socket, &QIODevice::readyRead,
    this, &mywindow::_processIncomingData
);
```

Then, in your class :

```
//Is called every time new data is sent to the socket 
void mywindow::_processIncomingData() {

    //prepare to receive data 
    QDataStream receiver(this->_innerSocket); 

    //will loop until the whole waitingBytes of the socket are exhausted 
    while(!receiver.atEnd()) { 

        //start a transaction, so the waitingBytes of the socket can be automatically reset if not all the expected data is there 
        receiver.startTransaction();

        //push waitingBytes into a QByteArray
        QByteArray myJsonAsLatin1;
        receiver >> myJsonAsLatin1;

        //commit : if it failed, means data is missing, so you may keep looping while the client downloads more
        if(auto commitFailed = !receiver.commitTransaction()) continue;

        //commit succeeded, waitingBytes are freed from your QByteArray, you can now process your data
        this->_useMyData(myJsonAsLatin1);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to set QAbstractSocket::setReadBufferSize() to a larger value, if the current value is too small. But this is an internal Qt buffer, and by default should be large enough. Most probably you need to set [QAbstractSocket::ReceiveBufferSizeSocketOption](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractsocket.html#SocketOption-enum) which is an OS level socket option. See QAbstractSocket::socketOption() and [QAbstractSocket::setSocketOption()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractsocket.html#setSocketOption).